# How to Load binary to Windows Media Player in Windows Forms VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, binary, media-player

I've successfully saved video files into SQL server as varbinary. Now, my problem is, how can I play those videos in Windows Media Player (embedded in my Windows Forms).

I've searched the internet but got no luck. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but my guess would be to investigate how to stream something a live webcam feed into WMP, and use your database to simulate the web-cam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read from the database and write it to a temp file when a video is to be viewed.  Then you can set the URL property to the temp file's full path like normal.  If you don't want the file to remain you can clean up after viewing, otherwise I might keep it to speed up future views. Just in case, here's [MSDN on embedding the Windows Media Control with VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: yes, thats what I'm thinking... I'll try it if I can't find solution. Thanks!